# Haskell - Finding general type

Tags: haskell

I am new in Haskell and I have problems with finding the type of

```
f x y = f y x
```

GHCI gives me: a->a->b

But I don't understand why. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Is it the complete code ? I'm not sure to understand what you did, but `f x y = f y x` can make sense only if `x` and `y` have the same type. This explains `a -> a`.

Comment: Yes this is the complete code. :t f gives me t1 -> t1 -> t. What you say was also my thought but GHCI says something else

Comment: You say `a -> a -> b` in your OP and now you say `t1 -> t1 -> t`. I don't follow you. Anyway `a` denotes an arbitrary type, like `t1`. This is the same. And you say "GHCI says something else". I'm lost.

Comment: And your code is not complete since you didn't type `:t f` in your OP. We have to guess what you mean...

Comment: Or you mean `b` ? `a` is the type of `x`, `a` is the type of `y`, and `b` is the type of `f x y`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's OK to use both `x` (on the left) and `y` (on the right) for the first argument of `f`, they must be the same type. So that's where the `a -> a` comes from.

Your function will infinitely recurse without returning anything, so you can correctly claim that it has an arbitrary return type because there's no situation where that will be falsified by it returning a value of another type, as it never returns. This is where the arbitrary `b` comes from.

Comment: The deduced return type of `f` is not determined independent of the argument types because of yieldless infinite recursion. In `f x y = f x y`, `f :: a -> b -> c` because no type coercions can be inferred. In `f x y = f y x`, `f :: a -> a -> b` because the argument type `a` is logically coerced, and the return type `b` is not.

Comment: `f x y = x + f x y` for example never terminates, but is of the constrained type `Num a => a -> b -> a`. Using `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`, `f :: Int -> a  -> Int`, with a specific return type `Int`.